# Как получить дату с calendarview?

Tags: java, android, calendar-view

Как получить дату с слушателя`setOnDayChangeListener` виджета `CalendarView`  и сохранить в `Post.class`

```
private void iniPopup(){
            popupAddPost = new Dialog(this);
            popupAddPost.setContentView(R.layout.popup_add_post);
            popupAddPost.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
            popupAddPost.getWindow().setLayout(Toolbar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, Toolbar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            popupAddPost.getWindow().getAttributes().gravity = Gravity.TOP;


            popupUserImage = popupAddPost.findViewById(R.id.popup_user_image);
            popupPostImage = popupAddPost.findViewById(R.id.popup_image);
            popupMoney = popupAddPost.findViewById(R.id.popup_money);
            popupDescription = popupAddPost.findViewById(R.id.popup_description);
            popupAddBtn = popupAddPost.findViewById(R.id.popup_add);
            popupClickProgress = popupAddPost.findViewById(R.id.popup_progressBar);
            popupCalendar = popupAddPost.findViewById(R.id.popup_calendar);

            Glide.with(Home.this).load(currentUser.getPhotoUrl()).into(popupUserImage);


            popupCalendar.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSelectedDayChange(@NonNull CalendarView view, final int year, final int month, final int dayOfMonth) {
                    **String date = dayOfMonth + "-" + month + "-" + year;**
                    //как это можно вытащить с слушателя и отправить в Post.class
                    //массивом пробовал никак
                    //###
                }
            });



            popupAddBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    popupAddBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    popupClickProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                    if(!popupMoney.getText().toString().isEmpty() && !popupDescription.getText().toString().isEmpty() && pickedImgUri != null){

                        StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("blog_images");
                        final StorageReference imageFilePath = storageReference.child(pickedImgUri.getLastPathSegment());
                        imageFilePath.putFile(pickedImgUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                                imageFilePath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                        String imageDownloadLink = uri.toString();                         
                                        //в этот post хочу сохранить в date
                                        //### 
                                        Post post = new Post(popupMoney.getText().toString(), popupDescription.getText().toString(), *date*, imageDownloadLink, currentUser.getUid(), currentUser.getPhotoUrl().toString());


                                        addPost(post);
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        });

                    }
                    else{
                        popupAddBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        popupClickProgress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Примерно вот так:

```
String date;

private void showDataPickerDialog() {
    if (getActivity() != null) {

        DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), dateSetListener,
                dateAndTime.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                dateAndTime.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                dateAndTime.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        datePickerDialog.show();
    }
}

  private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateSetListener =
        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar.set(year, month, day);
                SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault());
                date = formatter.format(calendar.getTime());

                Log.d("TAG", "onDateSet: " + date);
            }};
```

На выходе будет:

```
onDateSet: 2020-01-04
```

Или вот так еще можно:

```
  public String getCurrentDay() {
    calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date tomorrow = calendar.getTime();
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat =
        new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault());
    return dateFormat.format(tomorrow);
}
```

Comment: мне надо его загрузить в Объект Post post = new Post(String titile, String description, String date); при нажатие на кнопку popupAddBtn

Comment: после которого он загружает в Firebase

Comment: String date = formatter.format(calendar.getTime());

Comment: Надо что бы пользователь приложение выбирал дату сам, а не по умолчанию вот для этого слушатель

Comment: Есть две строки textview(String name, String lastname) calendarview(String date) и кнопка button(addpost). При нажатие на кнопку он собирает все в class Post и заполняет конструктор Post post = new Post(String name, String lastname, String date) и отправляет в базу данных Firebase

Comment: Мне неизвестно что вам надо, в вопросе спрашивается как получить дату - я вам показал пример слушаетля с установкой даты.

Comment: как можно вытащить дату с слушателя(метода) setOnDateChangeListener

Comment: в формате String date, мне не нужен Diolog, Log.d, Intent, а просто String

Comment: просто надо вынести из этого метода String date, чтобы туда записалась дата выбранная по календарю

Comment: нашел решение массивом

Comment: Обьявляете просто поле стринг в шапке String date; И далее при нажатии на диалог присваиваете date = formatter.format(calendar.getTime()); И у вас получается общедоступный стринг. Хотя бы так. Но вам надо сделать много чего еще что бы туба не попадал null в конструктор

Comment: Вот это и была проблемой

Comment: Решение String[] date = new String[1]; date[0] = day + month + year;. Post post = new Post(date[0]);